# How to get the data from sql using Date

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, datetime-format

How to get the data from sql using Date, I'm using the date datatype as varchar, I want to fetch the record from sql table. I want to fetch the last month data, for eg today date is 04/11/2014. From today minus one month 04/10/2014 so I want to search by this date 04/10/2014

I have tried this query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [IndxRpt] 
WHERE EcrCylinderNo IS NULL 
  AND OrderDate <= '04/10/2014'
```

And also I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [IndxRpt] 
WHERE EcrCylinderNo IS NULL 
  AND OrderDate <= (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '04/10/2014', 103))
```

But its showing the November month data also. How to get this?

Comment: _"iam using the date datatype as varchar"_ Why??

Comment: _i am using the date datatype as varchar_ Why? Why don't you keep them in a `datetime` or `datetime2` column type which is exactly what is for?

Comment: Also, if you want to consider a maximum end date, why not specify it in your SQL?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Comment: @SonerGönül this database is created before,now i am just upgrading the application.i dont have rights to change the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rationaly you should use OrderDate as DateTime data type. But still answering your question you need to cast OrderDate in Datetime Datatype and than apply any logical operation on it for filtration in WHERE condition.

So, your query will as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [IndxRpt] 
WHERE EcrCylinderNo IS NULL 
AND CONVERT(DATETIME,OrderDate,103) <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'04-OCT-2014',103)
```

Comment: It is recommended to pass DateTime value in 'DD-MMM-YYYY' format, to avoid DateTime conversion errors.

Answer (score 1):

1) If your OrderDate column type is varchar than for string value "<=" is not a good operator but if its datatype is date, time or datetime than only "<=", ">=" will work fine. So better to convert it into datetime and than compare it.

2) If you have starting and ending date than its better to convert your OrderDate column to datetime and then compare it using "between" clause.

Eg.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [IndxRpt] 
WHERE EcrCylinderNo IS NULL 
AND (CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(DATE, '04-OCT-2014')) 
--If SQL Server 2008 or above 

--Or For below
SELECT * 
FROM [IndxRpt] 
WHERE EcrCylinderNo IS NULL 
AND (CONVERT(DATETIME, OrderDate) BETWEEN GETDATE() AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '04-OCT-2014'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot change the column to a proper data type i would suggest converting it to datetime for your query.

E.G.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [IndxRpt] 
WHERE EcrCylinderNo IS NULL 
  AND CAST(OrderDate as DateTime)<=  '04/10/2014'
```